# IntlDateFormatter to date() format letters

Tags: javascript, php

I'm seeing a lot of (frontend) languages using the format options that come from the date() function but that doesn't lineup with what I get from IntlDateFormatter when using locales.

Is there a way to change what I get based on locale from IntlDateFormatter to a date() type format in d-m-Y in some way ?

I don't need the formatted date but the referenced format that date() would use.

Examples are:

dd-MM-yy -> d-m-y

dd-MMM-yy -> d-M-y

dd-MMMM-yy -> d-F-y

dd-MM-yyyy -> d-m-Y

dd-MMM-yyyy -> d-M-Y

dd-MMMM-yyyy -> d-F-Y

.. etc

Comment: can you add the date and format that you are getting and the expected way the output should be?

Comment: Added, good one!